# ListView OnItemClickListener not Working for Listview

Tags: android

I am using `listview` with `Customlist` Adapter, I am able to set data to list but not able to assign onItem click listener to list. Some of the code snippet is as follows :

```
private ListView listview;
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainOptionList);
customlistviewadapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, elements);
listview.setAdapter(customlistviewadapter);
```

With this I am able to assign data to list. I have attached clicklistener as follows :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
System.out.println("position" + position + " item at this position:" + adapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
}
```

Here I am not able to print output in `logcat`. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you have any click listener on your adapter?

Comment: If you facing any error na just put in your post...

Comment: implement OnItemClickListener with your activity and try again.

Comment: I have implenented OnItemClickListener with activity but not able to print outout as mentioned in post..

Comment: what is your mean about not Working? any error? please post adapter code too

Comment: use Log.d to get data in logcat

Comment: I am not getting any error but on click of list item i want to do something on click of list item which is not happening..

Comment: Try a toast message instead.

Comment: add a new logcat filter then only u can see your printed value in logcat..On left side of your logcat window click + sign and put ur package name in Filter name box like this(com.pckg (Session Filter)) and then paste ur pacakage name in by Application Name box then only you can see ur logcat...

Comment: Check your custom list adapter first, whether you have focusable element or not (e.g. checkbox, EditText, RadioButton, etc). IF they do exist, simply put android:focusable="false" and android:clickable="false" in each respective element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try to put toast on the click listener

**You just Use this code inside your Main Activity...**

```
    sListStudies.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long arg) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "position" + position + " item at this position:"
                            +                    adapter.getItemAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Naveen thanks a lot..this also works fine if i do not implement onclick listener for activity..but i wanted to do with implenenting on item click listener for activity which is told by Piyush..

Answer (score 1):

In your custom file named **listview_item_row** set this properties

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for your all UI elements.

Comment: adding to all UI elements is abit overkill LOL, but yeah.. it works :D

Didn't we just need to put it on focusable element? (such as EditText, CheckBox, etc)